# How to highlight areas of the image due to which the neural network classifies it as Covid

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I trained a keras model which classifies images as normal, pneumonia and covid-19. I need to highlight areas of the image to which the neural network reacts when classifying as Covid-19. I don't even know how to name this sort of thing and can't google it.

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you're trying to fix/create and also more information about the specific highlighting of the image.

Comment: do you mean sub region highlighting?

Comment: I don't have a problem with code. I simply don't know how to do it. I have an image of Chest X-Ray classified as Covid-19. And i want  to see why my model says it - i want to highlight the parts of image because of which my model decided that this is Covid(in other words - areas of the image to which the model reacts more intense)